# package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’

Tags: r, tidyverse, command-line-interface

I was using R before but suddenly I got this problem. I tried to solve by uninstalling and re-installing R and many more. I still have this problem. Looking for the suggestions to solve it.

> ```
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- 
> i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>  namespace ‘cli’ 3.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.4.1 is required
> ```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing of R.

Answer (score 0):

you should restart R after you install.packages('cli') but dont save workspace, it works for me, I had the same problem